# create leaflet rectangle from given 2 diagonal points

Tags: leaflet, geometry, geospatial, turfjs

i have a leaflet feature rectangle and i need to pragmatically draw another squre rectangle . see the image dotted rectangle is the one i need to calculate

**possible solutions**

1. get center of rectangle create new 4 point from center draw a rectangle
   i there any other better solutions for this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distance from square vertices to rectangle center is

```
d = rect_width / 2 + rect_height / 2
```

So their coordinates are

```
rect_center_x + d; rect_center_y  
rect_center_x; rect_center_y - d  
rect_center_x - d; rect_center_y  
rect_center_x; rect_center_y + d
```